# How do I refresh an ObjectSet via reflection in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am trying to do a generic refresh via reflection and the EntitySetName.

So what works is:

```
base.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this.Selections);
```

And what I am trying to do is:

```
base.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this.GetType().GetProperty("Selections").GetValue(this, null));
```

But that gives me the following exception:

> The element at index X in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager.

Is there any way I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

GetValue just returns an `object`, and Refresh (apparently) does not internally cast it to its actual type. And if you want to do this cast in your method, you're back where you started (having to know `this.Selections`).

Your only chance is to make a generic method like `Refresh<T>`, so you can refresh an `ObjectSet` directly:

```
base.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this.CreateObjectSet<T>());
```